# Preview, how can I return back to the previous position after clicking a link in the pdf file

Tags: preview

In Preview, how can I return back to the previous position after clicking a link in the pdf file? I found `command+[` or `command+]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the toolbar and add the `Page History` buttons.